# Lambda Edge Function trigger is getting removed automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have a static website hosted on s3 and I am serving it through cloudfront.
For routing I have used this lambda edge function

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
  const uri = request.uri;
  console.log("Original URI:", uri);

  // Regex to check if the path ends with a GUID
  const guidRegex =
    /^[{]?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[}]?$/;

  const intRegex = /^\d+$/;

  // Remove the trailing slash if present and not just the root "/"
  if (uri.endsWith("/") && uri.length > 1) {
    request.uri = uri.slice(0, -1);
  }

  // After removing trailing slash, check if we are now at the root
  if (request.uri === "/" || request.uri === "") {
    request.uri = "/index.html";
  }
  // Check if the last segment is a GUID
  else if (guidRegex.test(request.uri.split("/").pop()) || intRegex.test(request.uri.split("/").pop())) {
    const parts = request.uri.split("/");
    parts[parts.length - 1] = "[id]/index.html"; // Replace GUID with [id].html
    request.uri = parts.join("/");
  }
  // If there is no file extension, it's a first-level path
  else if (!request.uri.includes(".")) {
    request.uri += ".html";
  }

  console.log("Rewritten URI:", request.uri);
  return request;
};
```

I created 1 trigger and selected cloudfront over there.
Everything was working as expected when I accessed my static site.
But the next day, the functionality broke , and when I checked the lambda console, I saw that there is no trigger, trigger git removed automatically.

[image: trigger got removed automatically]

I don't know whats happening, please help!

I want that my lambda function functionality stays active always.
It should always resolve URI paths as expected. The cloudfront trigger should always be there.